# Are there any viable toy models of superdeterministic quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, determinism

As far as I know, [superdeterminism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdeterminism) in quantum mechanics is only considered as a theoretical possibility. Are there any fleshed out superdeterministic toy models so far *which isn't nonlocal*?

Comment: The nearest one I can think of is MWI, but that is just an interpretation. Any you thinking of something that gives different results to standard QM?

Comment: What is superdeterminism (in QM)? Can you explain what is that, in simple words? Deterministic models there are, of Bohm and of Ghirardi, Rimini, and Weber. (None good enough). But of $super$determinisn I never heard.

Comment: If a model is viable, in what sense is it a toy model?

Answer (score 2):

No superdeterminstic theory has been fleshed out, at least not sufficiently to be a viable theory. The most elaborate attempt is that of Gerard `t Hooft, but it is not a theory that can explain atoms and other complex systems described by quantum mechanics. Tim Palmer and Sabine Hossenfelder has done some work but it is no more than vague visions.

Answer (score 1):

Superdeterminism is really more conceptual than something you can flesh out. The Wikipedia article you link has a good quote in this regard:

> [W]e always implicitly assume the freedom of the experimentalist... This fundamental assumption is essential to doing science. If this were not true, then, I suggest, it would make no sense at all to ask nature questions in an experiment, since then nature could determine what our questions are, and that could guide our questions such that we arrive at a false picture of nature.

Similar possibilities that are a bit more interesting however are so-called supercorrelating interpretations, which Louis Vervoort gives an explanation of here (as well as a longer explanation of superdeterminism you might find interesting); DOI: [10.1007/s10701-013-9715-7](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6587).

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Bohmian mechanics is superdeterministic. You see, the pilot wave and the "particle" covers everything in the universe, including the experimentalist and the measuring apparatus. The location of the "particle" fixes the experimentalist's will and the detector settings superdeterministically. Neither the experimentalist nor the detector has any free will in bohmian mechanics.

Comment: This is incorrect. Superdeterminism refers to local hidden variable theories. BM is nonlocal.

Comment: Superdeterminism isn't the same as determinism. The Bohmian Mechanics isn't superdeterministic, but it is deterministic. Superdeterminism was introduced by John Bell as classification of deterministic theories such that given the initial conditions for the system to be measured there are restrictions of the initial conditions for its environment that prohibits certain settings of the measurement apparatus that we otherwise think should be allowed. For example, certain angles of a polarizing filters should be impossible though there is no clear detectable hindrance.